# Writing to a .txt file but my while loop is infinite

Tags: php

I am writing to a txt file using PHP but my while loop is infinitely looping. I saw the other questions and they mention the counter++ not being added but I have the incrementing counter. Why is my while loop infinitely looping? What I am trying to accomplish is only add one line of code each time the submit button is clicked on the html form.

PHP

```
    <?php

   if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']))
    {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $filename ='person.txt';

    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w'); 

    $cntr = 0;

    while(true){

        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

        if(empty($firstname) && empty($lastname))
        {
            break;
        }

        $cntr++;

        print($firstname . " " . $lastname . " " . "<br");
        $output = $firstname . " " . $lastname . "\n";
        fwrite($fp, $output);
    } //END OF WHILE LOOP

    }//END ISSET
    fclose($fp);


?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a While loop?

Comment: Your while loop never terminates, because every time you check $_POST['firstname'] and $_POST['lastname'] they are never empty.

Comment: Why you're using a `while` loop ?

Comment: What do you recommend I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any while loop. In place of while, Just do a if..else...

```
    if( (strlen($firstname) < 1) || (strlen($lastname) < 1) ){

        // do Nothing Or report error

    }else{

                print($firstname . " " . $lastname . " " . "<br");
                $output = $firstname . " " . $lastname . "\n";
                fwrite($fp, $output);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can get the loop to stop in your code is in with `break;`, which obviously isn't getting called.

Your counter doesn't contribute anything to the code except to increment itself. Since `while(true)` always evaluates as `true`, it will loop forever. If you want to use a counter, make the condition of the while loop `while($cntr < $max)`, but you need to define `$max` as a value, such as 10.

Comment: If I do not want to limit my loop, how do I correct my code?

Comment: @WCA: please edit your question to let us know the problem you're trying to solve with the `while` loop; because without that knowledge we're not really able to help you in any constructive manner (although it's worth pointing out that Phil seems to have answered your question as it's currently written.)

Answer (score 0):

Code is wrong here: 
`if(empty($firstname) && empty($lastname))
        {
            break;
        }`

If firstname and lastname are not empty then your loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set firstname and lastname they never empty.(according to
   your code).so the loop will infinite.
2. Another thing is your `$cntr`
       variable is not usable.it only increasing without no affect to your
       code.

if you want to correct this. just add below segment to inside bottom of while loop

$firstname = null;
$lastname = null;

```
while(true){

    if(empty($firstname) && empty($lastname))
    {
        break;
    }

    $cntr++;

    print($firstname . " " . $lastname . " " . "<br");
    $output = $firstname . " " . $lastname . "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $output);


    $firstname = null;
    $lastname = null;
}
```